# Hard code the input (value of range of Merged Cells) of an Excel sheet for Unit Test Case

Tags: c#

**-- Code for getting value from a range of Merged cells --**

```
 Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range range = sheet.get_Range(valueColumnAddress);
                                                System.Array rawValues = (System.Array)range.Cells.Value2;
```

**-- Format of Values Returned observed while Debugging  --**

```
rawValues -> System.Array{object[,]}
{
[1,1] - "value 1", 
[2,1] - "value 2",
[3,1] - "value 3",
[4,1] - "value 4"
} each of type (object{string})
```

The above Object Array is to be converted to String Array using the below method

```
string[] ConvertToStringArray(System.Array values)
    {


        string[] theArray = new string[values.Length];

        for (int i = 1; i <= values.Length; i++)
        {
            if (values.GetValue(i, 1) == null)
                theArray[i - 1] = "";
            else
                theArray[i - 1] = (string)values.GetValue(i, 1).ToString();
        }

        return theArray;
    }
```

To test the above method how to hardcode the input values i.e rawValues.
Kindly help me with this issue